# Why is SFINAE not applied in this example?

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

I expected the following minimal example to compile by application of SFINAE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct FallBack{};

struct S {
    int bar() { return 42; }
};

template <typename A, typename B>
std::enable_if_t< (std::is_same< std::enable_if_t<true==FLAG, FallBack>, FallBack>::value and std::is_convertible<B, std::string>::value), int >
    foo ( A a) { return a.bar();
}


template <typename A, typename B>
std::enable_if_t<false==FLAG, int>
foo ( A a) { std::cout << "false solution " << std::endl; return -1; }



int main()
{
    std::cout << foo<S, std::string>( S{}) << std::endl;
}
```

to compile it: 
`g++ -std=c++14 -DFLAG=1 myFile.cc`

If I comment the second `foo` function, everything works fine, therefore my understanding of SFINAE is incorrect; furthermore, the compiler complains about an ambiguity on the definition of `foo`.

I am evidently wrong, but cannot see the problem.
Could please anyone comment and explain why SFINAE is not applied?

Comment: Do you hate `#ifdef` that much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have non template dependent condition.

You should do something like

```
template <typename A, typename B>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<A, A>::value == FLAG, int>
foo (A a) { std::cout << "false solution " << std::endl; return -1; }
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes it compile; but I still need to define a compile flag, and the `enable_if` should take it into account it. I would like not to pass the `FLAG` as template parameter into the `foo` functions.

Comment: Release and Debug are going to have different values for it, for example.

Comment: @Jarod42 Using `template <typename B, typename A>` instead of `template <typename A, typename B>` would have `A` (that is, the type of the parameter) deduced.

Comment: @skypjack: I agree. I kept OP's order.

Comment: @Jarod42 Right, I've just disobeyed him with my answer. Nice. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use:

```
#if FLAG == 1
template <typename A, typename B>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<B, std::string>::value, int >
    foo ( A a) { return a.bar();
}
#else
template <typename A, typename B>
int foo ( A a) { std::cout << "false solution " << std::endl; return -1; }
#endif
```

Given that you're using a compile-time define anyway, it makes sense to use it to explicitly specify the definitions you need rather than rely on SFINAE entirely.

Comment: This is not going to work as other parts of the code specialize other methods based on the flag value, without using SFINAE.

Comment: Why don't you give an example of such 'other parts' of code so I understand the objection better?

Answer (score 1):

As already said by @Jarod42, sfinae expressions don't work with non template dependent conditions.

Anyway, if you can split it in two structs, here is a solution that does the job:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct S {
    int bar() { return 42; }
};

template <typename B, bool = FLAG>
struct T {
    template<typename A>
    static void foo ( A a ) {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<B, std::string>::value, "!");
        std::cout << a.bar() << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename B>
struct T<B, false> {
    template<typename A>
    static void foo( A a ) {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<B, std::string>::value, "!");
        std::cout << "false solution " << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    T<std::string>::foo(S{});
    T<std::string, true>::foo(S{});
    T<std::string, false>::foo(S{});
}
```

It is based on partial specialization instead of sfinae.
The drawback (or is it a feature?) of this solution is that you can still work around it and the value of `FLAG` by forcing the `bool` parameter explicitly.
See the code above for further details.

Comment: This is in fact solving the original problem, even if my question was about SFINAE. Thanks!